# Examples of Haskell Applicative Transformers

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, applicative

The wiki on www.haskell.org tells us the following about Applicative Transformers:

> So where are applicative transformers? The answer is, that we do not need special transformers for applicative functors since they can be combined in a generic way. 
>   http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applicative_functor#Applicative_transfomers

I tried the following in order to try to combine a bunch of applicative functors. But all I got was bunch of errors. Here is the code:

```
import Control.Applicative
import System.IO

ex x y = (:) <$> x <*> y 
test1 = ex "abc" ["pqr", "xyz"]  -- only this works correctly as expected
test2 = ex "abc" [Just "pqr", Just "xyz"]
test3 = ex "abc" (Just "pqr")
test4 = ex (Just 'a') ["pqr", "xyz"]
test5 = ex (return ("abc"):: IO ()) [Just "pqr", Just "xyz"]
```

This produces a lot of type errors, which though I can partially understand, I couldn't resolve them at all.

The errors are given at the end.

So, how do I combine the Maybe Applicative and the List Applicative for example?

How do I combine the State Applicative and the List Applicative for example?
Are there any other examples, let's say, combining Maybe and List, Maybe and State and finally the dreadful of all the IO and State applicatives?

Thanks.

The GHCi error msgs follow.

```
example.hs:6:19:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `Maybe a0'
    In the return type of a call of `Just'
    In the expression: Just "pqr"
    In the second argument of `ex', namely `[Just "pqr", Just "xyz"]'

example.hs:7:19:
    Couldn't match expected type `[[Char]]' with actual type `Maybe a0'
    In the return type of a call of `Just'
    In the second argument of `ex', namely `(Just "pqr")'
    In the expression: ex "abc" (Just "pqr")

example.hs:8:23:
    Couldn't match expected type `Maybe' with actual type `[]'
    In the second argument of `ex', namely `["pqr", "xyz"]'
    In the expression: ex (Just 'a') ["pqr", "xyz"]
    In an equation for `test4': test4 = ex (Just 'a') ["pqr", "xyz"]

example.hs:9:21:
    Couldn't match expected type `()' with actual type `[Char]'
    In the first argument of `return', namely `("abc")'
    In the first argument of `ex', namely `(return ("abc") :: IO ())'
    In the expression:
      ex (return ("abc") :: IO ()) [Just "pqr", Just "xyz"]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

Comment: Note that it's not entirely true that you don't need transformers anymore when using applicatives. E.g. `StateT s IO a` is an `Applicative`, but it's not a composition of any two applicatives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The wiki article says that `liftA2 (<*>)` can be used to compose applicative functors. It's easy to see how to use it from its type:

```
o :: (Applicative f, Applicative f1) =>
     f (f1 (a -> b)) -> f (f1 a) -> f (f1 b)
o = liftA2 (<*>)
```

So to if `f` is `Maybe` and `f1` is `[]` we get:

```
> Just [(+1),(+6)] `o` Just [1, 6] 
Just [2,7,7,12]
```

The other way around is:

```
>  [Just (+1),Just (+6)] `o` [Just 1, Just 6]
[Just 2,Just 7,Just 7,Just 12]
```

As @McCann said your ex function is equivalent to `liftA2 (:)`:

```
test1 = liftA2 (:) "abc" ["pqr", "xyz"]
```

To use `(:)` with deeper applicative stack you need multiple applications of `liftA2`:

```
*Main> (liftA2 . liftA2) (:) (Just "abc") (Just ["pqr", "xyz"])
Just ["apqr","axyz","bpqr","bxyz","cpqr","cxyz"]
```

However it only works when both operands are equally deep. So besides double `liftA2` you should use `pure` to fix the level:

```
*Main> (liftA2 . liftA2) (:) (pure "abc") (Just ["pqr", "xyz"])
Just ["apqr","axyz","bpqr","bxyz","cpqr","cxyz"]
```

Answer (score 13):

Consider the following type signatures:

```
liftA2 :: (Applicative f) => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
(<*>) :: (Applicative f) => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Combined, the resulting type is:

```
liftA2 (<*>) :: (Applicative f, Applicative g) 
             => f (g (a -> b)) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
```

This is indeed a combination of two `Applicative`s. In fact, it's a combination of *exactly* two `Applicative`s. In other words, although you *can* combine `Applicative`s in a generic way, this is not in any way way done *automatically*. Everything must be explicitly lifted the correct number of times.

Your `ex` function is equivalent to `liftA2 (:)`, which has type `(Applicative f) => f a -> f [a] -> f [a]`. Going through your examples, making some guesses about what you wanted to do:

```
test1 = ex "abc" ["pqr", "xyz"]
```

Here `f` is `[]`, and we're applying it to arguments of type `[Char]` and `[[Char]]`.

```
test2 = ex "abc" [Just "pqr", Just "xyz"]
```

The second argument is of type `[Maybe [Char]]`, so we need to lift twice. The first argument also needs to be lifted, since it has type `[Char]` and should be `[Maybe Char]`.

```
test3 = ex "abc" (Just "pqr")
```

This time the second argument is of type `Maybe [Char]`, so `f` is `Maybe` and we only need one lift. The first argument should therefore be of type `Maybe Char`.

```
test4 = ex (Just 'a') ["pqr", "xyz"]
```

This time the first argument is `Maybe Char` but the second is `[[Char]]`, so you have two completely different `Applicative`s; both will need to be lifted, to give you either `[Maybe Char]` or `Maybe [Char]`.

```
test5 = ex (return ("abc"):: IO ()) [Just "pqr", Just "xyz"]
```

The type signature here makes no sense; you probably wanted `IO [Char]`. The second argument has type `[Maybe [Char]]`. Like the previous example they don't match up, but this time you have *three* `Applicative`s. If you want something like `IO [Maybe a]`, you'll need to lift `(:)` all three times, e.g. `liftA2 (liftA2 ex)`.

This way of combining `Applicative`s is called "functor composition", and the page you linked to mentions libraries that define an explicit composition type constructor. For example, [using the `transformers` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Data-Functor-Compose.html), you could have a type like `Compose IO (Compose [] Maybe)` to describe your fifth example. This composed type is defined as an `Applicative` instance in the aforementioned generic way, and applies the correct number of lifting operations. The downside is that you'll need to wrap and unwrap the `newtype` layers this requires.

---

As an addendum, this statement:

> So where are applicative transformers? The answer is, that we do not need special transformers for applicative functors since they can be combined in a generic way.

...is a bit bogus. It's true that the composition of two `Applicative`s is also `Applicative`, but this is not the only way to combine `Applicative`s!

Consider `StateT s m a`, which is equivalent to `s -> m (s, a)`, though it's defined slightly differently. This could also be written as the composition of three functors: `((->) s)`, `m`, and `((,) s)`, and the resulting `Functor` instance would be correct, but the `Applicative` instance would be *completely* wrong. If you start with just `State s a = s -> (a, s)` instead, there's no way to define `StateT s m` by composing `State s` and `m`.

Now, observe that the non-composition combination `StateT s (Either e)` is essentially a simplified version of the typical parser combinator monad used in libraries like Parsec, and such parsers are one of the well-known places where using `Applicative` style is popular. As such, it seems more than a bit misleading to suggest that monad transformer-style combinations are somehow unnecessary or superfluous where `Applicative` is concerned!

Comment: The type signature is wrong?  Should it not be `liftA2 (<*>)  = f (g (a -> b)) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)` ?

Comment: It would be interesting to see an example of using `Compose` to see how much syntactic overhead it adds to the code.

Answer (score 5):

Saying they can be combined in a generic way does not mean they can be combined implicitly or invisibly or anything like that. =)

You still need to write a bit of code, either by using different mungers than `<*>` and `pure` or by adding some newtype noise. For example, using the [TypeCompose](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose) package, you might write

```
test2 = ex (O (Just "abc")) [O (Just "pqr"), O (Just "xyz")]
```

Comment: `Data.Functor.Compose` from the transformers package is probably the more commonly used data type for this. It also has `Data.Functor.Product`, which is a different way to combine applicative functors.

Comment: A bit more description about TypeCompose can be found at https://wiki.haskell.org/TypeCompose

Answer (score 5):

As usual, it's useful here to focus on the types to figure out what composition of applicative functors should mean.

If we write `a` for the type of a particular pure value `x`, that therefore has no side effects, then we can lift this pure value to a computation of the applicative functor `f` using the `pure` combinator. But by the same token, we can use the `pure` function from `g`'s `Applicative` instance to lift `pure x` into the `g` functor.

```
pure (pure x) :: g (f a)
```

Now `g (f a)` is the type of computations that combine the effects of `g` and the effects of `f`. Looking at your tests, we notice that

```
test1 :: [String]
```

You have used only one effect in `test1`, that is the non-determinism that the list instance of `Applicative` gives you. Indeed, breaking it down:

```
"abc" :: String
((:) <$>) :: [Char] -> [String -> String]
((:) <$> "abc") :: [String -> String]
((:) <$> "abc" <*> ["pqr", "xyz"]) :: [String]
```

Now, if we want to compose the failure effect and the non-determinism effect, we would expect to construct a computation of type `Maybe [a]`, or perhaps `[Maybe a]`. It turns out that the two are equivalent, because applicative functors always *commute*.

Here's a computation of type `[Maybe Char]`. It will non-deterministally return a `Char`, but if it does, it might fail:

```
x1 = [Just 'a', Just 'b', Just 'c']
```

Likewise, here's a computation of type `[Maybe String]`:

```
x2 = [Just "pqr", Just "xyz"]
```

Now we want to lift `(:)` to this combined applicative functor. To do so, we have to lift it it twice:

```
pure (pure (:)) :: [Maybe (Char -> String -> String)]
```

Likewise, to apply it, we need to push this computation through both functors. We can therefore introduce a new combinator `(<<*>>)` that does that:

```
(<<*>>) :: (Applicative f, Applicative f1) =>
           f (f1 (a -> b)) -> f (f1 a) -> f (f1 b)
(<<*>>) = liftA2 (<*>)
```

Which now allows us to write:

```
pure (pure (:)) <<*>> x1 <<*>> x2
```

which you can check has the expected type.

But since applicative functors are closed under composition, `[Maybe a]` is itself an applicative functor and so you may wish to be able to reuse `pure` and `(<*>)`. The `Data.Functor.Compose` module of the [transformers](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Data-Functor-Compose.html) package shows you how to.

Comment: It would be interesting to see an example of using Compose to see how much syntactic overhead it adds to the code.