# Haskell function from (a -> [b]) -> [a -> b]

Tags: list, function, haskell

I have a function `seperateFuncs` such that

```
seperateFuncs :: [a -> b] -> (a -> [b])
seperateFuncs xs = \x -> map ($ x) xs
```

I was wondering whether the converse existed, i.e. is there a function

```
joinFuncs :: (a -> [b]) -> [a -> b]
```

I think not (mainly because lists are not fixed length), but perhaps I'll be proved wrong.
The question then is there some datatype `f` which has a function :: (a -> f b) -> f (a -> b)?

Comment: Other than the trivial solution, I guess.

Comment: There is such a function for infinite lists, and for tuples of known length. Basically, i-th element of the output is the i-th projection of the input.

Comment: A different explanation might come from `Applicative f => Monad f`: every `f (a -> b)` can be turned into a `(a -> f b)`, but not necessarily the other way around (moreover, you can implement `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)` in terms of `(=<<) :: (a -> f b) -> (f a -> f b)`, but not always the other way around). Not sure about this, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can generalize `seperateFuncs` to `Applicative` (or `Monad`) pretty cleanly:

```
seperateFuncs :: (Applicative f) => f (a -> b) -> (a -> f b)
seperateFuncs f x = f <*> pure x
```

Written in point-free style, you have `seperateFuncs = ((. pure) . (<*>))`, so you basically want `unap . (. extract)`, giving the following definition if you write it in pointful style:

```
joinFuncs :: (Unapplicative f) => (a -> f b) -> f (a -> b)
joinFuncs f = unap f (\ g -> f (extract g))
```

Here I define `Unapplictaive` as:

```
class Functor f => Unapplicactive f where
    extract  :: f a -> a
    unap     :: (f a -> f b) -> f (a -> b)
```

To get the [definitions given by leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13766031/824425), you could give the following instances:

```
instance Unapplicative [] where
    extract = head
    unap f = [\a -> f [a] !! i | i <- [0..]]

instance Unapplicative ((->) c) where
    extract f = f undefined
    unap f = \x y -> f (const y) x
```

I think it's hard to come up with a "useful" function `f :: (f a -> f b) -> f (a -> b)` for any `f` that isn't like `(->)`.

Comment: By the way, in the same gist as [Matt Fenwick's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13768652/824425): you could see `coap` as an instance of `g (f a) (f b) -> f (g a b)`, so kinda like `sequenceA`, you are "transposing" a functor (`f`) and a bifunctor (`(->)`).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can brute-force yourself this function all right:

```
joinFuncs f = [\x -> f x !! i | i<-[0..]]
```

but this is obviously troublesome – the resulting list is always infinite but evaluating the `i`th element with `x` only succeds if `length(f x) > i`.

To give a "real" solution to

> The question then is there some datatype `f` which has a function `:: (a -> f b) -> f (a -> b)`?

Consider `(->)c`. With that, your signature reads `(a -> (c->b)) -> (c->(a->b))` or equivalently `(a -> c -> b) -> c -> a -> b` which, it turns out, is just `flip`.

Of course, this is a bit of a trivial one since `seperateFuncs` has the same signature for this type...

Answer (score 3):

**"Is there some datatype f which has a function :: (a -> f b) -> f (a -> b)?"**

In fact, there is an even more general version of this function in the [Traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html) type class, which deals with commutable functors:

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable t where

  ... 

  sequenceA :: Applicative f => t (f b) -> f (t b)
```

How is this related to your function?  Starting from your type, with one type substitution, we recover `sequenceA`:

1. `(a -> f b) -> f (a -> b)`   ==>  `let t = (->) a`
2. `t (f b) -> f (t b)`

However, this type has the constraint that `t` must be a Traversable -- and there isn't a Traversable instance for `(->) a`, which means that this operation can't be done in general with functions.  Although note that the "other direction" -- `f (a -> b) -> (a -> f b)` works fine for all functions and all Applicatives `f`.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently had to think quite a bit about problems that reduce to a question very similar to yours.  Here's the generalizations that I found.

First, it is trivial to do this (at Tinctorius pointed out):

```
f2m :: Functor f => f (a -> b) -> a -> f b
f2m f a = fmap ($a) f
```

But it is impossible to do this in general:

```
m2a :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m (a -> b)
```

One insightful way of understanding this, which somebody kindly explained to me in the #haskell irc channel, is that if there existed an `m2a` function, there would be no difference between `Applicative` and `Monad`.  Why?  Well, I don't follow it 100%, but it's something like this: `Monad m => a -> m b` is the very common type of monadic actions with one parameter, while `Applicative f => f (a -> b)` is the also very common type of what, for not knowing the proper name, I'll call "applicable applicatives."  And the fact that `Monad` can do things that `Applicative` cannot is tied to the fact that `m2a` cannot exist.

So now, applied to your question:

```
joinFuncs :: (a -> [b]) -> [a -> b]
```

I suspect the same "Monad /= Applicative" argument (which, again, let me stress, I don't fully understand) should apply here.  We know that the `Monad []` instance can do things that the `Applicative []` instance cannot.  If you could write a `joinFuncs` with the specified type, then the `[a -> b]` result must in some sense "lose information" compared to the `a -> [b]` argument, because otherwise `Applicative []` is the same as `Monad []`.  (And by "lose" information I mean that any function with `joinFuncs`'s type cannot have an inverse, and thus it is guaranteed to obliterate the distinction between some pair of functions `f, g :: a -> [b]`.  The extreme case of that is `joinFuncs = undefined`.)

I did find that I needed functions similar to `m2a`  So the special case that I found is that it's possible to do this:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

-- | Enumerate a monadic action within the domain enumerated by the 
-- argument list.
boundedM2a :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [(a,b)]
boundedM2a f = mapM f'
    where f' a = do b <- f a
                    return (a, b)

-- | The variant that makes a 'Map' is rather useful.
boundedM2a' :: (Monad m, Ord a) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m (Map a b)
boundedM2a' f = liftM Map.fromList . boundedM2a f
```

Note that in addition to the requirement that we enumerate the `a`s, an interesting observation is that to do this we have to "materialize" the result in a sense; turn it from a function/action into a list, map or table of some sort.

Comment: Yes:  [Applicatives commute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12588267/894284), [Monads might not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5901592/894284).

Comment: If an applicative functor F has the morphism `(a -> F b) -> F(a -> b)` then F is automatically a monad and has `(a -> F b) -> F a -> F b`. This is so because an applicative functor has `F(a -> b) -> F a -> F b`. Thus, the morphism `(a -> F b) -> F(a -> b)` cannot be a general property of all applicative functors -- otherwise all applicative functors would have been monads.

Answer (score 0):

The question "can I have function with type signature `joinFuncs :: (a -> [b]) -> [a -> b]` is incomplete without also saying what laws you want this function to satisfy. Without laws, you may solve this problem by defining `joinFuncs _ = []` (always returning an empty list). This trivial function satisfies the required type signature but is most likely useless.

One way of demanding that `joinFuncs` be useful is to impose the non-degeneracy law, `separateFuncs . joinFuncs == id`. Then one can show that it is impossible to implement `joinFuncs` for this type signature.

A more general case of this type signature is `(a -> f b) -> f (a -> b)` where `f` is some functor. I call such functors "rigid". See this question [Is this property of a functor stronger than a monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649497/is-this-property-of-a-functor-stronger-than-a-monad)  for more details.

All rigid functors `R` satisfy the property that the type `R ()` has only one distinct value, i.e. it is equivalent to `()`. This allows us to see right away that the `List` functor is not rigid, because `List ()` is not equivalent to `()`.

The simplest non-trivial example of a rigid functor is `type R a = (a -> p) -> a` where `p` is a fixed type. The functor `R` defined in this way is actually a rigid monad.