# Is it possible to write a function in haskell: (r -> [a]) -> [r -> a])?

Tags: haskell, types, inverse

Its inverse seems possible.
Since I imagine lists are products and `->` is exponentiation,
`(a*a*a...)^r = (a^r)*(a^r)....`

Since we can define the inverse `[a->r] -> a -> [r]` shouldn't it be possible to define this?

Comment: How about `const []`? ;) What I mean: what should the function do?

Comment: What I was trying to accomplish is, if a function returns a list of values, we should be able to create a list of functions that each of which should capture one index of the list.
I was thinking in terms of:  f &&& (g &&& (h ... ))) == (f, (g, (h, ...)))

Comment: The actual algebraic interpretation of lists is that `List A ~ 1 / (1 - A)`, and it does not hold that `1 / (1 - A^R) = (1 / (1 - A))^R`

Comment: [This older answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765324/haskell-function-from-a-b-a-b/13769761#13769761) might be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to *fix* the size of the list of functions then it'll work.

```
dn :: [r -> a] -> (r -> [a])
dn fns r = map ($ r)

up :: Int -> (r -> [a]) -> [r -> a]
up n f = tabulate n (\i r -> f' r !! i)
  where 
   f' = cycle . f
   tabulate n f = map f [0..n-1]
```

Now we can get `up` as the "sort of" left inverse of `dn`... provided we shuffle around some length information:

```
id1 :: [r -> a] -> [r -> a]
id1 ls = up (length ls) (dn ls)
```

and it can be the "sort of" right inverse of `dn` if we magically know (a) that for every `r` the length of the result list `[a]` is the same and (b) we know that length (called `magic` below)

```
id2 :: (a -> [b]) -> a -> [b]
id2 f = dn . up magic
```

This answer is basically equivalent to `copumpkin`s comment on `leftroundabout`'s answer, but instead of carrying it out using types I'm passing around the (fixed) length information manually. If you play with `up` and `dn` for a bit you'll see why this kind of thing won't work for lists in general.

Answer (score 8):

`[a] ≅ a*a*...` only holds for infinite lists. For these, your requested function is actually quite simple, though the naïve implementation isn't very efficient:

```
type InfiList = []

unwind :: (r -> InfiList a) -> InfiList(r -> a)
unwind f = [ \x -> f x !! n | n <- [0..] ]
```

Actually though, `[a] ≅ 1 + a * (1 + a * (1 + ...))`; here the power law doesn't work.

Comment: What if the list is finite? We can still define the inverse right?

Comment: @user3585010: you can still define _something_, but it won't be an isomorphism.

Comment: @user3585010: What would you do if the list was finite? For example, let's imagine a function `Int -> [Bool]` that returns `[]` except for `100` where it returns `[True, False]`. What would you expect the resulting `[Int -> Bool]` list to contain?

Comment: It's possible for finite lists of a given size (like `Vec` indexed by a length) or for infinite streams. What they have in common (and `List` does not) is that they can both be expressed as functions from an index set. `Vec n a ≅ Fin n -> a` and `Stream a ≅ Nat -> a`. In that case, the question reduces to calling `flip`. The original question has nothing guaranteeing homogeneity--one value of `r` could result in a list of one length, while another value of `r` could produce a list of a different length.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, this is impossible if the length of the lists is not known in advance.

This is because the type `r -> [a]` roughly stands for the following:

1. Take an input of type `r`
2. Output a natural number `n` (including infinite)
3. Output a list of `n` values of type `a`

As an example, take

```
replicateA :: Int -> [Char]   -- r = Int , a = Char
replicateA 0 = []
replicateA n = 'A' : replicate (n-1)
```

By comparison, the type `[r -> a]` roughly stands for the following:

1. Output a natural number `n` (including infinite)
2. In each of the `n` elements of the list:

   1. Take an input of type `r`
   2. Output a value of type `a`

Here the key fact is that the length of the list must be produced *before* knowing the `r` input. This can not be done, in general, since the length *can* depend on `r`, as the above `replicateA` example shows.